# How can I add an intro to a Windows Phone application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add a good welcome intro to my Windows Phone Application, like the Dropbox's one.The welcome's pages are very simple, I mean there will be just come text and image, and in the last one the user will be required to register or to login. What kind of layout/tecniques is possible to use ? This welcome intro should be display only if it is the first time, that the user opens the application, or if he hasn't registered to the service. I think the easiest way is to save same variable in the settings preferences memory, isn't it ? Thank you in advance for your suggestion !

**UPDATE**

What I'm looking for it is to create a welcome pages which describe to the user what the application does. The layout I'm looking for it is very similar to the Dropbox's one, which has some points at the end of the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a broad question, there are many ways on how to approach this. I would do it like this

- Create a IsLoggedIn method on my data service
- In App.xaml.cs, check if the user is logged in, if yes, launch with the main page, if not launch with the intro page
- In the intro page, I would use a FlipView. I would add one fake item at the end of the FlipView and redirect to the main page if the user flips to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No problem about the check for the logged session. The FlipView it is a good solution, but I don't think is the same of the Dropbox's one. This one has 3 points at the end of the page, and changes respect to the page. What do you suggest me to do the same ?

Comment: you can easily create a control displaying the dots according the data in FlipView, check out http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/08/24/A-CXAML-FlipView-Context-Indicator-for-Windows-8.aspx

Comment: I have created some images in photoshop and I want to swipe it under one single Page; how can I do ? What C# methods should I use to handle swipe right and left ?